# Save a remote image in to Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I tried using this code for download image:

```
void downloadImage(){
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://mysite/image.png"));

        }

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           //how get stream of image?? 
           PicToIsoStore(stream)
        }

        private void PicToIsoStore(Stream pic)
        {
            using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                var bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.SetSource(pic);
                var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bi);
                using (var isoFileStream = isoStore.CreateFile("somepic.jpg"))
                {
                    var width = wb.PixelWidth;
                    var height = wb.PixelHeight;
                    Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, isoFileStream, width, height, 0, 100);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is: how get the stream of image?

Thank!

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to get a stream to a file in Isolated Storage. `IsolatedStorageFile` has an [OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190070.aspx) method that gets one.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("somepic.jpg", FileMode.Open))
    {
        // do something with the stream
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to put `e.Result` as a parameter when calling `PicToIsoStore` inside your `client_DownloadStringCompleted` method

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,
     DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           PicToIsoStore(e.Result);
        }
```

The WebClient class gets response and stores it in the `e.Result` variable. If you look carefully, the type of e.Result is already `Stream` so it is ready to be passed to your method `PicToIsoStore`

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    PicToIsoStore(e.Result);
};
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://mysite/image.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
public static Stream ToStream(this Image image, ImageFormat formaw) {
  var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  image.Save(stream);
  stream.Position = 0;
  return stream;
}
```

Then you can use the following

```
var stream = myImage.ToStream(ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Comment: `System.Drawing.Image` is not available in Silverlight