# setting Live Tile back image issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-tile

I’m trying to implement the live tile to my app. This is the easier processes that I found online. But I get an Uri exception.

Here is the Code:

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InternetIsAvailable(); GetDataFeed(); BackTile();
    }

    public void BackTile()
    {
        StandardTileData backData = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(@"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27136243/AchivementHunters/Images/LatestTile.png", UriKind.Absolute),
        };
        ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
        tile.Update(backData);
    }
```

I want to update the back tile by just replacing the image. I see many tutorials that include servers, but I do not know anything about servers.

If I include the file in the soluction and use this:

```
            BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(@"LatestTile.png", UriKind.Absolute),
```

it works fine.

how can i download the image from the URL and save it the specific path needed for the back image?

Comment: Seriously, a picture of your exception?  Where's the picture of the inner exception?  Seriously, in future, just wrap it in a try/catch, and in a quickwatch do `theException.ToString()` and copy out the result.  It will contain all the info needed about the exception, its inner exceptions, etc.

Comment: Im new at this. So seriously I dont know all this. As i go through building my app and want to add stuff to it, I do some research and if I can get it then I ask here. Im learning programming on my own time and i dont know anyone that does programming. this it is the closer I can get to the programming community.

Comment: So, are you going to [edit] and add the exception info?  Would help you get a good answer, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [StandardTileData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata.backbackgroundimage%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) states that *"Secondary Tiles can be created only using local resources for images"*

You will need to use a WebClient to [download the image and save it to IsolatedStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870282/save-a-remote-image-in-to-isolated-storage) and then specify that [isostore URI](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/new-uri-schemes-windows-phone) for the live tile to use.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
BackgroundImage = new Uri("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27136243/AchivementHunters/Images/LatestTile.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

Your code is right, just remove '@' and use 'RelativeOrAbsolute'

Looks like fetching image from secured site i.e. with URL https, is not posible.